# Intuition behind $k$-algebra, $k$-algebra morphisms?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I will state the definition of a $k$-algebra and $k$-algebra morphisms.

> A ring $A$ equipped with a ring homomorphism $k \to Z(A)$ is called a $k$-algebra. More explicitly, this means that $A$ has a structure of vector space over $k$ and also a ring structure such that:
>
> (1) The operations "$+$" coming from the vector space structure and the ring structure, respectively, are the same.
>
> (2) The ring multiplication $\cdot$: $A \times A \to A$ is a $k$-bilinear map.
>
> One defines $k$-algebra morphisms as $k$-linear ring morphisms.

I understand these definitions formally, but I have quite a poor grasp on the intuition behind the definition of $k$-algebra and $k$-algebra morphisms. Could someone provide me with their intuitions on such?

Comment: I don't know what "intuition" means for $k$-algebras. Examples are perhaps more useful. Consider Lie algebras over $k$, for example, together with their morphisms. A Lie algebra is a $k$ algebra whose product is skew-symmetric, and instead of associativity, requires the Jacobi identity. Further examples are given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field).

Comment: Harmless self promotion [page 14](https://eoinmackall.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/abstract-algebra4.pdf). I think the original intuition behind an algebra was "an object which one could do algebra over the field $k$". The bilinear map is a multiplication of elements, if $A$ is unital then there is an isomorphic copy of $k\subset A$, and the vectorspace structure allows us to use $k$ as a field and insures abelian addition. Maybe matrices are useful examples since $\mathcal{M}_{n\times n}(k)$ is a (non-commutative for $n>1$) algebra over $k$. Field extensions $L/k$ are other good examples.

Comment: The idea that there is intuition available for everything is really, really wrong. Usually definitions are motivated by ideas, but it is seldom the case that those ideas are accessible to anyone who has just been presented with the definition. There are going to be lots of answers, providing things which are *not* intuitions...

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I wouldn't call Lie algebras an example of algebras...

Comment: My main intuition about $k$-algebras is that most of the time when you work with rings, you really want to work with $k$-algebras (although $k$ here can be an arbitrary commutative ring; restricting it to fields means losing some useful generality), because the ability to scale by elements of $k$ is useful very often. For instance, the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}\left[x\right]$ is actually a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra, not just a ring; and the $\mathbb{C}$-algebra structure is just as important (even though we usually call it "the polynomial ring" and not "the polynomial $\mathbb{C}$-algebra"). ...

Comment: ... Another example: If you have a polynomial $P$ with coefficients in $k$, you cannot evaluate it at an element of an arbitrary ring. But you can evaluate it at an element of a $k$-algebra.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: But this is not the meaning of "algebra" the OP is subscribing to, as visibile from his posting.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I just wanted to say, that $k$-algebra in the sense of A. A. Albert is also a common terminology (and does include Lie algebras).

Answer (score 4):

If $k$ is a field and $A$ is a unital $k$-algebra with unit $\mathbb{1}$, then $A$ is not only a $k$-vector space, but the scalars can be thought of as elements of $A$: the scalar $\lambda\in k$ can also be thought of as the scalar multiple $\lambda \mathbb{1}$ of the unit. A $k$-algebra homomorphism $\varphi : A \to B$ between $k$-algebras $A$ and $B$ is a ring homomorphism such that $\varphi(\lambda\mathbb{1}_A) = \lambda\mathbb{1}_B$ holds, that is, scalars in $A$ are sent to their corresponding scalars in $B$. This serves to rule out "strange" ring homomorphisms that don't preserve the $k$-algebra structure. For instance, consider the following example:

> **Example.** The polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra in a natural way. Now consider the ring homomorphism $\psi : \mathbb{C}[x] \to \mathbb{C}[y]$ given by $\lambda\cdot x^n \mapsto \overline{\lambda}\cdot y^n$. This is not a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra homomorphism: for instance we have $\psi(i) = -i$.

In general, if $A$ is a unital algebra over a commutative unital ring $R$ and $\alpha\in A$ is an element, then there is a unique unital $R$-algebra homomorphism $\varphi : R[x] \to A$ such that $\varphi(x) = \alpha$ holds. (If $p\in R[x]$ is a polynomial, then $\varphi(p)$ is simply the polynomial $p$ applied to $\alpha$.) The example above shows that there may be different ring homomorphisms with that same property (in the case $A = \mathbb{C}[y]$ and $\alpha = y$) that are not $k$-algebra homomorphisms.

In the study of non-unital algebras, a different definition of a $k$-algebra is customary. Now a $k$-algebra over a field $k$ is defined to be a $k$-vector space $A$ together with a multiplication such that $(A,+,\cdot)$ forms a [rng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_%28algebra%29) (that is, a ring without unit). In this case the scalars are not in general elements of $A$, and the algebra structure cannot be defined in terms of a homomorphism $k \to Z(A)$. Once again, a $k$-algebra homomorphism $\varphi : A \to B$ between $k$-algebras $A$ and $B$ is a linear map that preserves multiplication: $\varphi(xy) = \varphi(x)\varphi(y)$ for all $x,y\in A$, though we cannot require $\varphi$ to be [unital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_%28algebra%29#Unital_homomorphism). Regardless of whether the algebra is unital, I find it easier to think of a $k$-algebra as *a vector space equipped with multiplication* instead of *a ring together with a homomorphism*. (However if $k$ is not a field but an arbitrary ring, then a $k$-algebra is no longer a vector space.)

Comment: It's a ring! It's a vector space! It's a dessert topping!